# What are the commandments of Islam about Zakat to a relative?

Tags: zakat, family, sadaqah

My Uncle has a daughter and she is married. But they are so poor. Her husband didn't do any work and they have no mean of earning. Even they have no other source of livelihoods. Is it permitted in Islam to give Zakat to that daughter? And as a cousin other relatives also wanted to give Zakat to them is it permitted in Islam?
If anyone can guide properly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -3):

Zakat can be given to a poor relative, provided the recipient is not a Syed.

Comment: ' Recipient is not a Syed ' I didn't get the meaning of this. Please if you can briefly explain.

Comment: Zakat cannot be given to a Syed.